# How to be able to get multiple response in RxJava?

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I have this code below and I want to know how to be able to get additional response other than the set `Boolean` value:

```
public Single<Boolean> uploadFile(String entityType, String entityId, String blobName){
    return Single.create(e -> {
        uploadElement = DOM.createElement("input");
        uploadElement.setAttribute("type", "file");
        uploadElement.setAttribute("accept", "*/*");;
        Event.sinkEvents(uploadElement, Event.ONCHANGE);
        Event.setEventListener(uploadElement, event -> {
            final FileObject fileObject = (FileObject) getFile(event);
            log("Name=" + fileObject.getName());
            log("Type=" + fileObject.getType());
            log("Size=" + fileObject.getSize() + "");
            readAsDataURL((FileObject) fileObject, new FileReaderCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onLoad(String data) {
                        Entity entity = new Entity(entityType);
                        entity.setEntityId(entityId);
                        entity.setBlobProperty(blobName, data).subscribe(isSuccess -> {
                            e.onSuccess(isSuccess);
                        }, error -> {
                            e.onError(error);
                        });
                }
            });
        });
        click();
    });
}
```

I need to be able to get the `FileObject` also in the process, how can I do that in RxJava?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the zip operator. That makes a tuple of you result plus what you put in the zip operator. 
You might have to restructure your program a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `Single<Boolean>`, you could return a `Single<MyCustomResult>`, where `MyCustomResult` has a `boolean` field and a `FileObject` field.

Instead of `e.onSuccess(isSuccess)` you'd write:

```
e.onSuccess(new MyCustomResult(isSuccess, fileObject));
```